# Merge multiple GeoPackage raster tilesets

Tags: gdal, tiles, geopackage

I have multiple GeoPackage raster tilesets. They have the same tiling scheme created with GDAL using `-co TILING_SCHEME=GoogleMapsCompatible` option. They also have the same projection `EPSG:3857`

The GeoPackages only contain data in one zoom level.

Is it possible to merge these GeoPackages into one GeoPackage?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can import datasets from other GeoPackages into the current one. The easiest way would be to use [`ArcGIS 10.5/Pro Add Raster To GeoPackage GP Tool`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/add-raster-to-geopackage.htm). There is a [`raster2gpkg`](https://github.com/Esri/raster2gpkg) Python based GP Tool for ArcGIS 10.3+ versions as well.

```
arcpy.AddRasterToGeoPackage_conversion("c:/data/Maps.gpkg/main.SanDiego", "c:/data/san_diego.gpkg", "SanDiego", "TILED")
```

`Maps` is the GeoPackage name and `main.SanDiego` is the raster table name you need to import. You can explore the rasters inside a GeoPackage using the catalog window.

You could achieve this with [`gdal`](http://www.gdal.org/drv_geopackage_raster.html) tools as well. ( Make sure the gdal is build with sqlite support )
Usage:
View all rasters inside GeoPackage name:

`% gdalinfo sample.gpkg`

Translation of a GeoPackage raster into a separate GeoPackage with new raster name

```
% gdal_translate -of GPKG GPKG:sample.gpkg:Test existing.gpkg -co APPEND_SUBDATASET=YES -co RASTER_TABLE=new_table
```